# Why Am I Getting Unexpected URLConnection defaultUseCaches

Tags: eclipse

All of a sudden my Eclipse environment is getting this error.  Code compiles fine from command line so what gives?  I have changed nothing around caches.  Please don't tell me I have to reinstall Eclipse - why would it get corrupted if that is the case?

Unexpected URLConnection defaultUseCaches

Comment: Perhaps it is this issue Bug 465514 - Unexpected URLConnection defaultUseCaches enabled https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465514

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I came across this Error on Maven build process.

Comment: I have the same problem when using spring STS 3.8.2 with the plugins `org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender` message: `Unexpected URLConnection defaultUseCaches enabled` , `eclipse.buildId=3.8.2.201610040743-RELEASE-e46
java.version=1.8.0_112`

Comment: i keep getting this annoying error too. due to the bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465514 they say that "It is safe to ignore the message if Eclipse does not crash as described in bug 442524." - but hey, i just get spammed by this error every few seconds. i tried to close the error log view, but when the error occurs, it just reopens the view and makes it on top... very annoying...

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem by closing Eclipse and re-running  it with the `-clean` option:

```
Eclipse.exe -clean
```

Comment: This happened to me when I deleted the target folder (not knowing that was a maven thing).  Simply closing Eclipse did the trick (after rebuilding the maven project, dunno if that matters)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue last week in Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)

Our site decided to secure our Nexus Repository Manager by blocking http access.  Updated my settings.xml file to specify the https protocol for my mirror settings:

```
  <mirror>
     <id>nexus</id>
     <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
     <url>https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </mirror>
```

After changing the protocol from "http" to "https" I started getting java warnings and errors due to missing dependencies.  Looking at the error log, I see this unexpected url connection issue.

In my case, the problem stems from the fact that the SSL certificate for our Nexus server is issued by a corporate CA that is not installed in jre/lib/security/cacerts.  This is not a problem for command line builds because we have the SSL certificate installed in a user local trustStore and reference the trustStore in MAVEN_OPTS:

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Users/myusername/.keystore

We also include this system property in the configuration for installed JREs in Eclipse.  When performing a Maven build from command line, or via "Run As Maven Build" menu in Eclipse, the build is successful because the system property specifies the local trustStore.

Unfortunately, if we add a dependency to the project, or update to a version that does not exist in our local maven repo (~/.m2/repository/..._) we see java errors in the markers view, and we see this error in the error log.  This issue stems from the fact that Eclipse m2e plugin uses an internal Java compiler that is running in the JVM that is used to launch eclipse.  The JVM that is running Eclipse does NOT have the trustStore specified, so the SSL certificate is not available, and it is not able to resolve dependencies that doe not exist in the local repository.

The issue can be resolved by:
1. update eclipse.ini to add -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Users/myusername/.keystore to the -vmargs section.  This solves the problem as it relates to accessing our Nexus server, but it breaks the Eclipse update mechanism since the SSL certificates needed to retrieve updates are no longer available.  We don't like this solution.
2. add the SSL certificate for our Nexus server to jre/lib/security/cacerts.  We don't like this because it a) tampers with the JRE distribution, and b) requires that we make this update every time we upgrade the JRE.
3. run a manual build whenever a dependency is added or version is updated to force stand-alone maven to pull the new dependency into local maven repository.  This is what we are going with for now.

Personally, I think this is an Eclipse or m2e issue.  It seems that if Eclipse is going to use internal tools for dependency resolution, then it should have some mechanism to accept java system properties needed to specify the necessary trustStore.  Put another way, it should be possible to specify distinct trustStore files for Eclipse updates, and m2e builds.